# How to query for distance from NSString addresses in Parse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

For my iOS application, I need to organize a list of Parse objects by their distance from the user's current location. Each of the Parse objects has an attribute for location, but the location is a regular address in the form of an NSString, rather than GPS coordinates or a CLLocation.

I have two questions for this situation:

1. How do I find the distance between an NSString location and the user's current location?
2. How do I query for the distance in Parse (for example, only display the objects within 5 miles)?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform distance queries, you need a GeoPoint. There are many ways to look up a GeoPoint given a string address.

You could create an Cloud Code after-save method that uses Google to lookup the GeoPoint and add it to the record. Looking up the GeoPoint from a string is an expensive operation, you only want to do this once for each data point when the data changes.

To attempt to find distance based on a string address within a query (would require every record to be evaluated every time) would unfairly tax the geo-lookup facility and probably be a breach of the terms of use.

Once you have an actual GeoPoint in your data then the query is quite easy, as per [the documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#geo-query/iOS):

> To limit the results using distance check out `whereKey:nearGeoPoint:withinMiles`, `whereKey:nearGeoPoint:withinKilometers`, and `whereKey:nearGeoPoint:withinRadians`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I knew there was something simple I was missing.